# Simultaneously running multiple Python scripts on different kernels (Windows OS)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, command-line, multiple-instances

I would like to run several different python scripts (that is, not sharing the same code) at the same time, using different kernels. I saw there are some solutions for UNIX-based systems, such as [this](http://supervisord.org/), but I use Windows. Is there perhaps a python package dedicated for this purpose, or some other workaround from the command line?